# Vetification: Mixture Distribution Properties.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I hope some of you can help me with the verification of my proof for the next Excercise. And also let me know if I need to make some changes to it in case I decide to take $J=\mathbb{N}$.

> **The Excercise**
>
> Let $j=\{1,2,...,n\}$, $\{\mu_j\}_{j \in J}$ be probablity measures and let $\{\lambda_j\}_{j \in J}$ non-negative real numbers such that $\sum_{i \in I}\lambda_j=1$.
>
> $v=\sum_{j \in J}\lambda_j \mu_j$.
>
> a) Prove $v$ is as well a probability measure.
>
> b) Prove $\phi_X^v(t)=\sum_{j \in J}\lambda_j\phi_X^{\mu_j}(t)$
>
> c) Prove $\int_{\Omega}xdv=\sum_{j \in J}\lambda_j \int_{\Omega}xd\mu_j$.
>
> Note that $\phi_X^v(t)$ refers to the characteristic function of V.

Edit.

On c) X is integrable respect to each $v, \mu_j$.

Also, can I affirm that, only with the assumption that X is integrable respec to $v$, then X is integrable respect to each $\mu_j$?

I don't think so but would like to be certain about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Attempt of Solution**

---

**a)**

Note that $v(\emptyset)=0$ holds trivially. Also observe that $v(\Omega)=1$ becomes a problem of solving for $\lambda_j, \forall j \in J$.

Now, let $\{A_k\}_{1 \leq k}$ a set of disjoint events, then

$v(\cup_{1 \leq k}A_k)=\sum_{j \in J}\lambda_j \mu_j (\cup_{1 \leq k}A_k)=\sum_{j \in J}\lambda_j \sum_{1 \leq k} \mu_j(A_k)=\sum_{1 \leq k} \sum_{j \in J}\lambda_j \mu_j(A_k)$.

Therefore, $v(\cup_{1 \leq k}A_k)=\sum_{1 \leq k}v(A_k)$.

---

**b)**

$\phi_X^v(t)=\int_{\Omega}e^{itX}dv=\int_{\Omega}e^{itX}d(\sum_{j \in J}\lambda_j\mu_j)=\int_{\Omega}\sum_{j \in J}e^{itX}\lambda_jd\mu_j=\sum_{j \in J}\lambda_j\int_{\Omega}e^{itX}d\mu_j$.

Therefore, $\phi_X^v(t)=\sum_{j \in J}\lambda_j\phi_X^{\mu_j}(t)$.

---

**c)**

Note that $\int_{\Omega}Xdv=\sum_{j \in J}\lambda_j \int_{\Omega}d\mu_j$ refers to $E_v[X]=\sum_{j \in J} \lambda_j E_{\mu_j}[X]$.

Now, to prove this, lets use b) as the moment generatring function:

$i^{-1}\frac{d}{dt}\phi_X^v(t)=i^{-1}\frac{d}{dt}[\sum_{j \in J}\lambda_j\phi_X^{\mu_j}(t)]=\sum_{j \in J}\lambda_j[i^{-1}\frac{d}{dt}\phi_X^{\mu_j}(t)]$.

And evaluating in $t=0$, our result is given:

$i^{-1}\frac{d}{dt}\phi_X^v(0)=E_v[X]=\sum_{j \in J} \lambda_j E_{\mu_j}[X]=\sum_{j \in J}\lambda_j[i^{-1}\frac{d}{dt}\phi_X^{\mu_j}(0)]$.

---

More than once I interchanged integrals, derivatives, and sums. Those under the observation that the indexes of the sums, and the integrals have no relation, and based as well on the convergence of what's inside them in each case.